# Why is my DCOM client locking on a call to SendMessage?

Tags: c++, client, deadlock, atl, dcom

Running on XP. I have a client that calls calls `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)`, loads a (local) DCOM object, and attaches an event interface so the DCOM object can send back events. The client looks a lot like notepad with a multi-line textbox covering the client area to display event messages. Here are the calls that create a lock-up:

- Client calls `p->DoStuff()` on the DCOM object.
- The DCOM object calls `c->DoStuffEvent()` on the client while processing `DoStuff()`.
- The client sends a `EM_REPLACESEL` message to the child textbox to have it display "stuff is happening"

The client freezes on the `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)`. The client's call to `p->DoStuff()` is done on a the main thread while the `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)` is done on a different thread. I'm sure this has something to do with the problem.

Can someone explain what's causing the lock and how I might work around it? The client and DCOM objects are coded by me in MSVC/ATL, so I can modify them both as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that the window was created by the main thread.  So that is the only thread that can call the window proc.  When you `SendMessage` from the other thread, what it actually does it to put the message into the main thread's queue and then wait for the main thread to call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`.  Inside the call to `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`, Windows notices a waiting cross-thread `SendMessage` and passes that message to the window proc, then it wakes the second thread and lets it continue.

If you don't care about the return value of `SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)`, you can use [SendNotifyMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644953(VS.85).aspx) instead.  But if you do this, you need to make sure that the string you pass with the `EM_REPLACESEL` message is still valid when the message is finally delivered.

Comment: Yes, this makes perfect sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) documentation, SendMessage does not return until the function is completed. It is synchronous. I believe it is always answered on the UI thread as well. If you want to do an asynchronous message pass, then you should use [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944(VS.85).aspx).